# Finding number of entanglements within a triangle

Tags: algorithm

[image: Example Image]

Suppose your given a triangle and n projectiles like the lines in the example. Now each projectile has a starting point position, ending point position, and a probability. All starting and ending position are represented in a `tuple (s, alpha) where s is in {0, 1, 2}` which specifies the side of the triangle (in clockwise order) and `0 <= alpha <= 1` specifies how far along the side the point is (also in clockwise order). If any two projectiles do actually meet, the probability for them to create an entanglement is `pi x pj` (where pi and pj are the probability of the two projectiles).

What you need to do is calculate the total number of possible entanglements in this triangle with n projectiles and it should be within `O(nlogn)`

I am pretty stuck and don't really know how I can start to design this, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let call the triangle ABC. Let MN and PQ be 2 projectiles. There are 2 cases:

- M, N, P, Q lies on only 2 sides of ABC. WOLG, say  M and P are on AB and N and Q is on AC, and AM > AP. These two projectiles are to cross iff AN < AQ. In other words, the set of projectiles crossing MN of this type are those with the first point between AM and the second point outside AN (aka between NC). So to count the probability of this kind of entanglement:

  1. collect the set of projectiles that ends on AB and AC
  2. sort the projectiles by distance to A on AB.
  3. build and keep track of a range tree of the distance to A on AC (or some type of tree/data structure that can query sum(pj such that xj > x) in O(logN))
  4. iterate over the projectiles from A to B, for each projectile i (MN), (4i) query the sum(pj) in the range tree such that distance to A on AC > AN, (4ii) add pi*sum(pj) to the answer (this works because the projectiles in the range tree so far should have the distance to A on AB less than M), (4iii) add (AN, pi) to the range tree
- The second type is when M, N, P, Q lie on all the 3 sides. WOLG, say M and P are on AB, N is on AC and Q is on BC. This is easier because the necessary and sufficient condition is that AP < AM. So we just need to sort all the projectiles start on AB and ends on BC by distance to A on AB, and for each MN, we can query the sum of pj of those projectiles with distance to A on AB less than AM.

We then do it for each pairs of sides (so 3 times for the first type and 6 times for the second type). So it should be O(N logN) in total.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Though I am a little bit confused about why it would be 6 times for the second type

Comment: Also do you have any recommendations of the data structure I could use for query sum?